# How to convert VB Project to VBA project?

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have VB project of VSTO Word Add-In. I want to convert VB project to VBA project.

Is it possible to convert VB project to VBA project? or I need to create new project and rewrite all the functionality?

Comment: please visit [ask] and [mcve] and you may fix your question before you get it closed down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  VB.Net and VBA are different languages.  VB.Net supports many features not found in VBA.  AS far as I know there are no automatic converters.  You will need to manually rewrite.